# button on top of mask

Tags: swift3, ios10

I have a viewcontroller, that has a few things set up in Storyboard - specifically 3 buttons.

I am animating stuff behind the buttons, that shows "through" them, and have created a mask view, that should hide the animation. That works. Problem is, that I do not know hos to put the buttons on top of the mask view. They are also hidden by it. I have tried thing like `button.layer.zPosition = 1`, but to no avail. The red color is for visibility.

```
        let bottomMaskStart = contentText.frame.origin.y+contentText.frame.height
        bottomtMaskView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: bottomMaskStart, width: rangeView.frame.origin.x, height: self.view.frame.height-bottomMaskStart))
        bottomtMaskView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.view.addSubview(bottomtMaskView)
        self.playButton.layer.zPosition = 1
```

Would appreciate a helping hand.

The animation going behind as a line, drawn with core graphics - called every 100 ms with the current apmlitude of the mic:

```
func rangeWaveForm(){
        let viewHeight = self.rangeView.frame.height
        let db = viewHeight - (CGFloat(self.calculateVoiceLevel())/maxDb)*viewHeight
        let p = CGPoint(x:self.lastPoint.x+10, y: db)
        self.drawLineFromPoint(start: self.lastPoint, toPoint: p, ofColor: UIColor.blue, inView: customView)

        self.lastPoint = p
}



func drawLineFromPoint(start : CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint, ofColor lineColor: UIColor, inView view:UIView) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addLine(to: end)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        if(end.x > view.frame.width*0.95){

            let newRect = CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x-10, y: view.frame.origin.y, width: view.frame.width+10, height: view.frame.height)
            view.frame = newRect

        }
        if(start != CGPoint.zero){
            view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A mask that cuts a hole in a layer / view cuts that same hole in all the sublayers / subviews in front of that hole.

You can place a view in front of the hole, but it will *not* be visible if it is a subview of the view being masked.